# How Can I receive the GetListItems from Sharepoint List using SOAP?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, soap

I need to get the list items from SharePoint List.

I'm doing that locally. I've tried using this code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var listName = "Backlog";
        makeSoapCall(listName);
    });

function makeSoapCall(listName){
    var soapEnv =
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
      <soap:Body> \
        <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
          <listName>" + listName + "</listName> \
          <viewName></viewName> \
          <query></query> \
          <viewFields></viewFields> \
          <rowLimit></rowLimit> \
          <queryOptions></queryOptions> \
          <webID></webID> \
        </GetListItems> \
      </soap:Body> \
    </soap:Envelope>"

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://server/site/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: soapEnv,
    complete: resultsFeedback,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=\"utf-8\""
  });

}

function resultsFeedback(xData, status) {
    console.log("xData: " + xData);
    console.log("status: " + status);
}
```

Then, I received this message:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://server/site/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?callback=jQuery11100353987290…stItems%3E%20%20%20%3C/soap:Body%3E%20%3C/soap:Envelope%3E&_=1396538736189". jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Lists.asmx:3

xData: [object Object] report.html:37
status: parsererror
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.
Edson Martins

Comment: You may also want to use a third party library that will make it easier to deal with Sharepoint web services like http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/ or http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datatype property of ajax call object is incorrect. It should be "xml". Also your "contentType" property should have application/xml value instead of json.Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://server/site/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapEnv,
    complete: resultsFeedback,
    contentType: "application/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The application is running locally, cross domain, if I use XML the access is denied, jsonp is used for cross domain.

With XML I received this message:
401 (Unauthorized)

xData: [object Object] report.html:37
status: error

Comment: You get access denied not because of cross domain calls but because that you not authorized to SharePoint. Depending on version of SharePoint that you are using you have different ways to authorize.

Comment: Do you know how to get permission? I'm trying with:

<Login xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
    <username>user@domain</username> \
    <password>password</password> \
</Login> \

Comment: You can try to provide user name and password in ajax call https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. userName:"userName", password:"password" but i'm not sure that it will work in all scenarios.

Comment: Also you can try something like described here http://www.tonytestasworld.com/post/2009/06/04/How-To-Authenticate-and-Use-SharePoint-Web-Services-in-an-FBA-SharePoint-site.aspx

Comment: I've tried with username and password, but didn't work. I'll continue the tests. Thanks.